# Discrepancy on number of delete votes needed between priviledge page and FAQ

Tags: discussion

The **"When should I delete questions?"** part of the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says that *" the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers."*

Item **"Users with reputation ≥ 10k"** of the **"How can a post be deleted?"** part of the FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) states *"It takes three votes to delete; more if the question is popular, but ten votes at most."*

These two statements seem a little different with respect to the *"ten votes at most"* phrase. Am I misunderstanding the statements or is one of them incorrect?

To respond to some comments. There are two separate documents and they state different things. One says that *"the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers."* Thus a question with 50 votes would need 50 delete votes. However the other document contradicts that statement and says that a maximum of 10 votes is needed. This leaves me confused. The two documents say different things. Which should I believe?

Comment: What seems to be the discrepancy? As far as I read, the first doesn't exclude the second, but you could be reading them differently. Or is it that the first one isn't as specific and can cause confusion for readers who don't read the second?

Comment: What it's conveying is it takes at *least three* and at *most ten* votes to delete a question.

Comment: "Scales with" does not require or imply any particular scale function "if vote <5 then 3,  if vote >=5 then 10" fits fine with my understanding of "scales with"... "scales linearly" would be different story.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [canonical meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071) (linked to from that [FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) sentence *"It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), but ten votes at most."*) that announces that scaled delete votes are being implemented, you see this:

> - Popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 *(sic)* - a question's popularity is defined as: question score + top-scored answer score. For example, a question with (question score 15 + top answer score 5 = 20) will require 4 deletion votes (3 base votes + 1 popularity vote).

Thus, the number of votes do, in fact, scale *linearly* at a rate of 1:20.

Now *"scales **to** the number of votes"* is an unusual (incorrect?) way of saying the more usual *"scales **with** the number of votes"*. As Alexei pointed out in a comment, *"scales with"* does not necessarily imply *"scales linearly with"*, but you are correct in that it is commonly used to mean precisely that. What it *doesn't* mean is that it scales linearly at a rate of ***1:1***.

Also from the same [canonical meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071):

> - The maximum number of delete votes needed will not exceed 10.

Thus, a concise way to express the number of votes required to delete a question would be:

**The number of delete votes required to delete a closed question starts at a base of 3, scales linearly at a rate of 1:20 with respect to the sum of the votes on the question and the top-scored answer, and is capped at 10.**

The main problem with that note in the Help Center's [Access To Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) 10k privileges page about the number of votes required, is that it omits the cap. It also wouldn't hurt if it was a *little* clearer.

A rewrite of the note could look something this:

> It takes **3** votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales with the number of votes on the question and the top-scored answer. (At a rate of 1:20, and to a maximum of **10**.)